# LG V40 completely unresponsive.. Won't charge after I was playing with the partitions and 9008 mode.. Any options?

Tags: unbricking, partitions, lg, flashtool

I have an LG V40 through sprint.. Its won't respond to any button combos or cords /cables.. Anyone think they could help me out